# Sending data along with a redirect function to a another function in controller with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to send data with a redirect function to another function within a controller here are my codes

1.

```
function index($id) {
  redirect("/names/particular/", $id, 'refresh');
}
```

2.

```
function particular($id){

    $fno=$this->uri->segment(3);
    $this->load->model('names_rank');

    $this->data["names"]=$this->names_rank->get_particular($id);
    $this->load->view("view/details", $this->data);

}
```

I want to redirect with $id from function index in 1 to function particular within controller with function shown in 2..
I need help please

Comment: Are they both in the same controller?

Comment: Check if `_remap()` [method](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html#remapping-method-calls) can help.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you better pass it through session or flash data.

```
//to set a flash data
$this->session->set_flashdata('id',$id);
redirect('/names/particular/') ;
//to access this flash data
$data = $this->session->flashdata('id');
```

But if you wish to send using redirect method then you can give this a try.

```
$id=1;
redirect(base_url()."/names/particular/".$id);
```

you can excess by any method as :

```
 $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put dot to concatinate with $id like this: redirect("names/particular/".$id, 'refresh'); 
And i'm not sure about 'refresh',if it belongs there at all!